# Scrolling though objects then creating a new instace of this object

Tags: java, object, selection, instanceof

In my game when pressing the right mouse button you will place an object on the ground. all objects have the same super class (GameObject).
I have a field called selected and will be equal to one certain gameobject at a time.
when clicking the right mouse button it checks whats the instance of selected and that how it determines which object to place on the ground. code exapmle:
t is the "slot" for which the object will go to.

```
if (selected instanceof MapleTree) {
    t = new MapleTree(game,highLight);
} else if (selected instanceof OakTree) {
        t = new OakTree(game,highLight);
}
```

Now it has to be a "new" instance of the object. Eventually my game will have hundreds of GameObjects and I don't want to have a huge if else statement. How would I make it so it scrolls though the possible kinds of objects and if its the correct type then create a new instance of it...?

When pressing E it will switch the type of selected and is an if else statement as well. How would I do it for this too? here is a code example:

```
if (selected instanceof MapleTree) {
        selected = new OakTree(game);
} else if (selected instanceof OakTree) {
    selected = new MapleTree(game);
}
```

Comment: trying to remake minecraft are we :)

Comment: I like how every single post in here that has to do with java and games someone has to say that exact thing, maybe instead of doing that you could help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd be well of using [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

OR

You could use a HashMap of factory method(s) if you want to stick with the explicit route.

OR

If you want to go implicit and automagic you could use reflection to operate on the class of instance and retrieve the constructor which is then called: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html

OR

A hybrid of some of the above approaches would be to make sure that each class also implements a static (or not) factory method like `getInstance()` and then when you have the object you're matching you could just call that factory method directly on that object (or on it's class to keep static static).  This is somewhat automatic but still easier to follow.

Comment: But when using prototype how would I scroll though the possible objects though?

Comment: You'd clone the existing selected one, no conditionals needed.  `selected` becomes a prototype.

Comment: Seems to work for the first problem but I cant see how I would do it for the second one.

Comment: It doesn't work when using it it does not give me a "new" instance.

Comment: Just iterate through a collection of prototypes

Comment: when i change the location of one, its changes all of the instance's locations

Comment: Then use a static factory method rather than clone

Comment: That would mean your clone needs to be fixed. Just go with the factory method

Comment: You could also just go with a fake prototype where you use an instance factory method instead, and that would still allow you to copy some instance variables.

Answer (score 0):

I know little about Java, but would suggest you at least trade in your very long if-else tree for the better readable and probably faster [switch statement](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_switch_statements.html).

Comment: You can't use instanceof in a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using some reflection. It assumes that by convention you have the same constructor signature in all of your GameObject subclasses.

If you want to 'scroll through the list of all objects', you would have to maintain a set of all the different classes yourself. Then you could use the same method to construct a new one as cloning and existing one.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
public class GameTest {

public static class Game {
    // TODO
}
public static abstract class GameObject {
    protected GameObject( Game game ) {
        // TODO
    }
}

public static class MapleTree extends GameObject {
    // Copy constructor
    public MapleTree( MapleTree tree, Game game ) {
        super( game );
        // TODO, copy
    }
}

public <T extends GameObject> T buildNew( Class<T> clazz, Game game ) {
    try {
        final Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor( Game.class );
        return constructor.newInstance( game );
    }
    catch ( NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
        | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
        | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public GameObject cloneSelected( GameObject selected, Game game ) {
    return buildNew( selected.getClass(), game );
}
}
```